# http to https giving redirect loop error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

In my .htaccess file:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This is giving me a redirect loop error in Chrome when I visit `mydomain.io`.

I have  a free SSL certificate set up on CloudFlare, I'm not sure if that could be causing the issue? When I visit `https://mydomain.io` it works fine and comes up with the green lock and https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule instead on [cloudfare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170536-How-do-I-redirect-all-visitors-to-HTTPS-SSL-):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: This seems to work on Chrome Mac OSX 10.10, but on XP Chrome (virtual machine) it gives me an error: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but this seems to work for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine for me, while it is the first RewriteRule in my htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: This one still gives an error, but the cloudflare answer below works except on XP Chrome for whatever reason.

Comment: @frosty if the same error (redirect loop) occurs, you have to find the issue somewhere else (not htaccess)